# How to make a query show results for the last 6 days?

Tags: sql, oracle

Im looking for some help with the task of making a query based on SYSDATE show SYSDATE to SYSDATE-6
so i have this query, that works and shows results like [image]

i need to make it show the stats for the last 6 days instead of just today, so the columns would be

Facility Activity, Today, Yesterday, 2days ago, 3 days ago, 4 days ago,5 days ago, 6 days ago

```
SELECT 'Lines/Units Picked' AS "Facility Activity",
       COUNT(DISTINCT ptt.line_item_id) || '/' || NVL(SUM(ptt.nbr_units), 0) AS "Total"
FROM   prod_trkg_tran ptt
WHERE  ptt.tran_type = '500'
AND    ptt.tran_code IN ('001',
                         '007',
                         '010')
AND    ptt.whse = 'DCV'
AND    TRUNC(ptt.create_date_time) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND    ptt.nbr_units > 0
AND    ptt.task_id IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Orders/Lines/Units Shipped' AS "Facility Activity",
       COUNT(DISTINCT oo.tc_order_id) || '/' || COUNT(DISTINCT ooli.line_item_id) || '/' ||
       NVL(SUM(ooli.shipped_qty), 0) AS "Total"
FROM   outpt_orders oo
INNER  JOIN outpt_order_line_item ooli
ON     oo.tc_order_id = ooli.tc_order_id
WHERE  TRUNC(oo.created_dttm) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND    oo.o_facility_alias_id = 'DCV'
AND    oo.do_status < 200
AND    ooli.shipped_qty > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fill Rate of Shipped Lines/Units' AS "Facility Activity",
(CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ooli.line_item_id)
               FROM   outpt_order_line_item ooli
               INNER  JOIN outpt_orders oo
               ON     ooli.tc_order_id = oo.tc_order_id
               WHERE  TRUNC(ooli.created_dttm) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
               AND    oo.o_facility_alias_id = 'DCV') = 0 OR
               (SELECT SUM(ooli.orig_order_qty)
                                    FROM   outpt_order_line_item ooli
                                    INNER  JOIN outpt_orders oo
                                    ON     ooli.tc_order_id = oo.tc_order_id
                                    WHERE  TRUNC(ooli.created_dttm) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                                    AND    oo.o_facility_alias_id = 'DCV') = 0 THEN '0% / 0%' ELSE
       ROUND(((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ooli.line_item_id)
                FROM   outpt_order_line_item ooli
                INNER  JOIN outpt_orders oo
                ON     ooli.tc_order_id = oo.tc_order_id
                WHERE  ooli.shipped_qty > 0
                AND    TRUNC(ooli.created_dttm) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                AND    oo.o_facility_alias_id = 'DCV') /
             (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ooli.line_item_id)
               FROM   outpt_order_line_item ooli
               INNER  JOIN outpt_orders oo
               ON     ooli.tc_order_id = oo.tc_order_id
               WHERE  TRUNC(ooli.created_dttm) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
               AND    oo.o_facility_alias_id = 'DCV') * 100),
             1) || '% / ' || ROUND((((SELECT SUM(ooli.shipped_qty)
                                    FROM   outpt_order_line_item ooli
                                    INNER  JOIN outpt_orders oo
                                    ON     ooli.tc_order_id = oo.tc_order_id
                                    WHERE  TRUNC(ooli.created_dttm) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                                    AND    oo.o_facility_alias_id = 'DCV') /
                                 (SELECT SUM(ooli.orig_order_qty)
                                    FROM   outpt_order_line_item ooli
                                    INNER  JOIN outpt_orders oo
                                    ON     ooli.tc_order_id = oo.tc_order_id
                                    WHERE  TRUNC(ooli.created_dttm) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                                    AND    oo.o_facility_alias_id = 'DCV')) * 100),
                                 1) || '%' END) AS "Total"
FROM   dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'iLPNs/Units Received' AS "Facility Activity",
       NVL(SUM(ptt.nbr_of_cases), 0) || '/' || NVL(SUM(ptt.nbr_units), 0) AS "Total"
FROM   prod_trkg_tran ptt
WHERE  ptt.whse = 'DCV'
AND    TRUNC(ptt.create_date_time) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND    ptt.tran_type = '100'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ASNs Verified' AS "Facility Activity",
       TO_CHAR(COUNT(asn.asn_id)) AS "Total"
FROM   asn
WHERE  asn.destination_facility_alias_id = 'DCV'
AND    TRUNC(asn.verified_dttm) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'PO Lines/LPNs Putaway' AS "Facility Activity" 
     , COUNT(DISTINCT REF_FIELD_1 || REF_FIELD_2) || '/' || COUNT(DISTINCT CASE_NBR)                   "Total"
FROM (
    SELECT TO_CHAR(CREATE_DATE_TIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY')            "DTTM"
         , CASE_NBR
         , COALESCE(PT.REF_FIELD_1, LPN.TC_ASN_ID)             "REF_FIELD_1"
         , COALESCE(PT.REF_FIELD_2, LPN.ASN_ID || LPN.ITEM_ID) "REF_FIELD_2"
    FROM PIX_TRAN PT
       , LPN
    WHERE ( ( PT.TRAN_TYPE = '300'
              AND PT.TRAN_CODE = '01'
              AND PT.ACTN_CODE = '20' )
            OR ( PT.TRAN_TYPE = '300'
                 AND PT.TRAN_CODE = '04'
                 AND PT.ACTN_CODE = '21' ) )
          AND SUBSTR(COALESCE(PT.REF_FIELD_1, LPN.TC_ASN_ID)
                   , 1
                   , INSTR(COALESCE(PT.REF_FIELD_1, LPN.TC_ASN_ID)
                           , '_'
                           , 1)) != 'Return_'
          AND PT.CASE_NBR = LPN.TC_LPN_ID (+)
          AND PT.WHSE = 'DCV'
          AND TRUNC(CREATE_DATE_TIME) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
)
GROUP BY DTTM
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Replenishment Tasks/Units Completed' AS "Facility Activity",
       COUNT(DISTINCT th.task_id) || '/' || NVL(SUM(td.qty_pulld), 0) AS "Total"
FROM   task_hdr th
INNER  JOIN task_dtl td
ON     th.task_id = td.task_id
WHERE  th.whse = 'DCV'
AND    TRUNC(th.mod_date_time) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND    th.invn_need_type = 1
AND    th.task_genrtn_ref_code = '1'
AND    th.stat_code = 90
AND    td.stat_code = 90
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Cycle Counts Completed' AS "Facility Activity",
       TO_CHAR(COUNT(*)) AS "Total"
FROM   cnt_invn_hdr cih
WHERE  cih.whse = 'DCV'
AND    cih.stat_code = 90
AND    TRUNC(cih.create_date_time) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Percentage of Warehouse Counted' AS "Facility Activity",
       ROUND(((COUNT(DISTINCT cih.locn_id) / COUNT(DISTINCT lh.locn_id)) * 100),
             1) || '%' AS "Total"
FROM   locn_hdr lh
LEFT   OUTER JOIN resv_locn_hdr rlh
ON     lh.locn_id = rlh.locn_id
LEFT   OUTER JOIN cnt_invn_hdr cih
ON     lh.locn_id = cih.locn_id
AND    cih.stat_code = 90
AND    TRUNC(cih.mod_date_time) <= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
WHERE  lh.whse = 'DCV'
AND    (lh.locn_class = 'A' OR (lh.locn_class = 'R' AND rlh.sort_locn_flag = 0 AND
      rlh.inbd_staging_flag = 'N' AND lh.work_grp = 'RESV'))
```

i have found the below example as a template that works fine and i have been trying to convert my query into this template

```
SELECT ACTIVITY
     , SUM(CASE
             WHEN ACTIVITY_DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
             THEN QTY
             ELSE 0
         END) "TODAY"
     , SUM(CASE
             WHEN ACTIVITY_DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1)
             THEN QTY
             ELSE 0
         END) "YESTERDAY"
FROM (
    SELECT 'TEST1'        ACTIVITY
         , TRUNC(SYSDATE) ACTIVITY_DATE
         , 10             "QTY"
    FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT 'TEST2'
         , TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1 ACTIVITY_DATE
         , 20                 "QTY"
    FROM DUAL
)
GROUP BY ACTIVITY
ORDER BY ACTIVITY;
```

i can get each individual sub query to work from SYSDATE to SYSDATE-6 but when putting them all together thats when i have issues
ive tried everyway i can think of/google but no good.
but i always end up with either of these 3 errors when trying to convert it
ORA-00904
ORA-00936
ORA-01790

Updated im now trying with just 2 subquiries just to get it working. this is what ive got so far, cant seem to get rid of the error though

```
     , SUM(CASE
             WHEN DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
             THEN QTY
             ELSE 0
         END) "TODAY"
     , SUM(CASE
             WHEN DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1)
             THEN QTY
             ELSE 0
         END) "YESTERDAY"
FROM (
SELECT 'Lines/Units Picked'        AS "FACILITY_ACTIVITY"
                     , TRUNC(PTT.CREATE_DATE_TIME) AS "DATE"
                             , COUNT(DISTINCT PTT.LINE_ITEM_ID) || '/' || NVL(SUM(PTT.NBR_UNITS) , 0)  AS "QTY"
                FROM WMS2018.PROD_TRKG_TRAN PTT
                WHERE PTT.TRAN_TYPE = '500'
                      AND PTT.TRAN_CODE IN ( '001', '007', '010' )
                      AND PTT.WHSE = 'DCV'
                      AND TRUNC(PTT.CREATE_DATE_TIME) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                      AND PTT.NBR_UNITS > 0
                      AND PTT.TASK_ID IS NOT NULL
                GROUP BY TRUNC(PTT.CREATE_DATE_TIME)
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Percentage of Warehouse Counted' AS "FACILITY_ACTIVITY"
                     , TRUNC(CIH.MOD_DATE_TIME)          AS "DATE"
                     , ROUND(((COUNT(DISTINCT CIH.LOCN_ID) / COUNT(DISTINCT LH.LOCN_ID)) * 100), 1) || '%'   AS "QTY"
                FROM WMS2018.LOCN_HDR      LH
                LEFT OUTER JOIN WMS2018.RESV_LOCN_HDR RLH
                ON LH.LOCN_ID = RLH.LOCN_ID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN WMS2018.CNT_INVN_HDR  CIH
                ON LH.LOCN_ID = CIH.LOCN_ID
                   AND CIH.STAT_CODE = 90
                   AND TRUNC(CIH.MOD_DATE_TIME) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                WHERE LH.WHSE = 'DCV'
                      AND ( LH.LOCN_CLASS = 'A'
                            OR ( LH.LOCN_CLASS = 'R'
                                 AND RLH.SORT_LOCN_FLAG = 0
                                 AND RLH.INBD_STAGING_FLAG = 'N'
                                 AND LH.WORK_GRP = 'RESV' ) )
                GROUP BY TRUNC(CIH.MOD_DATE_TIME)
    )
GROUP BY FACILITY_ACTIVITY
ORDER BY FACILITY_ACTIVITY
;



                SELECT 'Lines/Units Picked'        AS "FACILITY_ACTIVITY"
                     , TRUNC(PTT.CREATE_DATE_TIME) AS "CREATED"
                             , COUNT(DISTINCT PTT.LINE_ITEM_ID) || '/' || NVL(SUM(PTT.NBR_UNITS) , 0)  AS "DATE"
                FROM WMS2018.PROD_TRKG_TRAN PTT
                WHERE PTT.TRAN_TYPE = '500'
                      AND PTT.TRAN_CODE IN ( '001', '007', '010' )
                      AND PTT.WHSE = 'DCV'
                      AND TRUNC(PTT.CREATE_DATE_TIME) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                      AND PTT.NBR_UNITS > 0
                      AND PTT.TASK_ID IS NOT NULL
                GROUP BY TRUNC(PTT.CREATE_DATE_TIME)
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Percentage of Warehouse Counted' AS "FACILITY_ACTIVITY"
                     , TRUNC(CIH.MOD_DATE_TIME)          AS "CREATED"
                     , ROUND(((COUNT(DISTINCT CIH.LOCN_ID) / COUNT(DISTINCT LH.LOCN_ID)) * 100), 1) || '%'   AS "DATE"
                FROM WMS2018.LOCN_HDR      LH
                LEFT OUTER JOIN WMS2018.RESV_LOCN_HDR RLH
                ON LH.LOCN_ID = RLH.LOCN_ID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN WMS2018.CNT_INVN_HDR  CIH
                ON LH.LOCN_ID = CIH.LOCN_ID
                   AND CIH.STAT_CODE = 90
                   AND TRUNC(CIH.MOD_DATE_TIME) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                WHERE LH.WHSE = 'DCV'
                      AND ( LH.LOCN_CLASS = 'A'
                            OR ( LH.LOCN_CLASS = 'R'
                                 AND RLH.SORT_LOCN_FLAG = 0
                                 AND RLH.INBD_STAGING_FLAG = 'N'
                                 AND LH.WORK_GRP = 'RESV' ) )
                GROUP BY TRUNC(CIH.MOD_DATE_TIME)
            )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include all data from six days ago onwards then change all the places you do `TRUNC(<column>) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)` to a range, e.g.:

```
AND    TRUNC(ptt.create_date_time) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

becomes

```
AND    ptt.create_date_time >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 6
```

If you can have data in the future then you can also put an upper limit on them, e.g. up to right now:

```
AND    ptt.create_date_time <= SYSDATE
```

or everything today even if it's later than now:

```
AND    ptt.create_date_time < TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1
```

but that may not be necessary.

As a bonus, if those date columns have simple indexes then this approach would allow those indexes to be used, whereas looking at `TRUNC(<column>)` would not as every row would have to have its value truncated before it could be compared.

---

It's unclear if you want a single count for the whole range or a count per day. If the latter then include the truncated relevant date column - e.g. `TRUNC(ptt.create_date_time)` - in the select list of each branch of the union, and also include a group-by clause for that in each branch. The first branch might then look like:

```
SELECT 'Lines/Units Picked' AS "Facility Activity",
       TRUNC(ptt.create_date_time) as "Date",
       COUNT(DISTINCT ptt.line_item_id) || '/' || NVL(SUM(ptt.nbr_units), 0) AS "Total"
FROM   prod_trkg_tran ptt
WHERE  ptt.tran_type = '500'
AND    ptt.tran_code IN ('001',
                         '007',
                         '010')
AND    ptt.whse = 'DCV'
AND    ptt.create_date_time) >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 6
AND    ptt.nbr_units > 0
AND    ptt.task_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY TRUNC(ptt.create_date_time)
```

You can then use that as an inline view and use conditional aggregation to turn that into a column per day, or use the `pivot` operator to do that. (If that is what you want - your template approach seems to suggest that, at least.) Except then you would need to work with the day offset rather than the actual date; so `TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(ptt.create_date_time)`, which would give a numeric value of 0 to 6 to pivot against.

Comment: see the update at the bottom of the post

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it looks to me that you need the MODEL clause to get the result. It is hard to replicate the problem without the data, though, I think that your data actualy looks or could be prepared to look like here:

```sql
--  S a m p l e   D a t a :
WITH
    tbl (WHSE, TRAN_CODE, TRAN_TYPE, CREATE_DATE_TIME, LINE_ITEM_ID, NBR_UNITS, TASK_ID, SHIPPED_QTY, ORDER_ID) AS
        (   
          Select 'DCV', '001',  '500',  To_Date('15.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    'LI_1',     50,     'TI_1',     40, 1       From Dual Union All
          Select 'DCV', '001',  '500',  To_Date('16.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    'LI_1',     20,     'TI_2',     20, 1       From Dual Union All
          Select 'DCV', '001',  '500',  To_Date('17.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    'LI_1',     30,     'TI_3',     20, 2       From Dual Union All
          Select 'DCV', '001',  '500',  To_Date('18.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    'LI_2',     50,     'TI_4',     25, 2       From Dual Union All
          Select 'DCV', '001',  '500',  To_Date('19.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    'LI_2',     50,     'TI_5',     45, 3       From Dual Union All
          Select 'DCV', '001',  '500',  To_Date('19.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    'LI_3',     20,     'TI_6',     20, 4       From Dual Union All
          Select 'DCV', '001',  '500',  To_Date('20.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    'LI_3',     10,     'TI_7',     10, 5       From Dual Union All
          Select 'DCV', '001',  '500',  To_Date('20.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    'LI_3',     10,     'TI_8',     10, 6       From Dual Union All
          Select 'DCV', '001',  '500',  To_Date('23.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    'LI_3',     30,     'TI_9',     20, 7       From Dual Union All
          --
          Select 'DXX', '002',  '400',  To_Date('15.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    'LI_9',     50,     'TI_10',    50, 12      From Dual Union All
          Select 'DXX', '002',  '400',  To_Date('16.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    'LI_7',     50,     'TI_11',    45, 12      From Dual Union All
          Select 'DXX', '002',  '400',  To_Date('17.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    'LI_6',     80,     'TI_12',    70, 12      From Dual Union All
          Select 'DXX', '002',  '400',  To_Date('18.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    'LI_6',     90,     'TI_13',    70, 12      From Dual Union All
          Select 'DXX', '002',  '400',  To_Date('19.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    'LI_9',     40,     'TI_14',    40, 17      From Dual Union All
          Select 'DXX', '002',  '400',  To_Date('20.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    'LI_6',     30,     'TI_15',    25, 17      From Dual Union All
          Select 'DXX', '002',  '400',  To_Date('20.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    'LI_6',     30,     'TI_16',    25, 17      From Dual Union All
          Select 'DXX', '002',  '400',  To_Date('20.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    'LI_7',     30,     'TI_17',    25, 18      From Dual Union All
          Select 'DXX', '002',  '400',  To_Date('23.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),    'LI_8',     50,     'TI_18',    40, 19      From Dual 
        )
```

Thee MODEL clause alows you to manipulate the data from different rows/columns and to create your own rows/columns prety much like you would do in  excel sheet. Part of your Facility Activities could be fetched like here:

```sql
--  M a i n   S Q L :
SELECT WHSE, FACILITY_ACTIVITY, TODAY, YESTERDAY, TWO_DAYS_AGO, THREE_DAYS_AGO, FOUR_DAYS_AGO, FIVE_DAYS_AGO, SIX_DAYS_AGO 
FROM  ( SELECT    WHSE, FACILITY_ACTIVITY, TODAY, YESTERDAY, TWO_DAYS_AGO, THREE_DAYS_AGO, FOUR_DAYS_AGO, FIVE_DAYS_AGO, SIX_DAYS_AGO
        FROM (   Select      WHSE, TRAN_CODE, TRAN_TYPE, 
                            CREATE_DATE_TIME, 
                            LINE_ITEM_ID, NBR_UNITS, TASK_ID, SHIPPED_QTY, ORDER_ID,
                            CAST('xxx' As VarChar2(32)) "FACILITY_ACTIVITY",
                            CASt('0/0' as VarChar2(32)) "TODAY",  
                            CASt('0/0' as VarChar2(32)) "YESTERDAY",
                            CASt('0/0' as VarChar2(32)) "TWO_DAYS_AGO",
                            CASt('0/0' as VarChar2(32)) "THREE_DAYS_AGO",
                            CASt('0/0' as VarChar2(32)) "FOUR_DAYS_AGO",
                            CASt('0/0' as VarChar2(32)) "FIVE_DAYS_AGO",
                            CASt('0/0' as VarChar2(32)) "SIX_DAYS_AGO"
                From        tbl t
            )
          MODEL     Partition By  (WHSE)
                    Dimension By  (FACILITY_ACTIVITY, CREATE_DATE_TIME, TASK_ID)
                    Measures      ( TRAN_CODE, TRAN_TYPE, LINE_ITEM_ID, NBR_UNITS, SHIPPED_QTY, ORDER_ID,
                                    TODAY, YESTERDAY, TWO_DAYS_AGO, THREE_DAYS_AGO, FOUR_DAYS_AGO, FIVE_DAYS_AGO, SIX_DAYS_AGO
                                  )
          RULES   (   TODAY['Lines/Units Picked', To_Date('11.10.2062', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '-'] = Count(DISTINCT LINE_ITEM_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 0), ANY] || '/' || Nvl(Sum(NBR_UNITS)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 0), ANY], 0),
                      YESTERDAY['Lines/Units Picked', To_Date('11.10.2062', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '-'] = Count(DISTINCT LINE_ITEM_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1), ANY] || '/' || Nvl(Sum(NBR_UNITS)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1), ANY], 0),
                      TWO_DAYS_AGO['Lines/Units Picked', To_Date('11.10.2062', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '-'] = Count(DISTINCT LINE_ITEM_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 2), ANY] || '/' || Nvl(Sum(NBR_UNITS)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 2), ANY], 0),
                      THREE_DAYS_AGO['Lines/Units Picked', To_Date('11.10.2062', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '-'] = Count(DISTINCT LINE_ITEM_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 3), ANY] || '/' || Nvl(Sum(NBR_UNITS)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 3), ANY], 0),
                      FOUR_DAYS_AGO['Lines/Units Picked', To_Date('11.10.2062', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '-'] = Count(DISTINCT LINE_ITEM_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 4), ANY] || '/' || Nvl(Sum(NBR_UNITS)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 4), ANY], 0),
                      FIVE_DAYS_AGO['Lines/Units Picked', To_Date('11.10.2062', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '-'] = Count(DISTINCT LINE_ITEM_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 5), ANY] || '/' || Nvl(Sum(NBR_UNITS)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 5), ANY], 0),
                      SIX_DAYS_AGO['Lines/Units Picked', To_Date('11.10.2062', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '-'] = Count(DISTINCT LINE_ITEM_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 6), ANY] || '/' || Nvl(Sum(NBR_UNITS)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 6), ANY], 0),
                      --
                      TODAY['Orders/Lines/Units Shipped', To_Date('11.10.2062', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '-'] = Count(DISTINCT ORDER_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 0), ANY] || '/' || Count(DISTINCT LINE_ITEM_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 0), ANY] || '/' || Nvl(Sum(SHIPPED_QTY)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 0), ANY], 0),
                      YESTERDAY['Orders/Lines/Units Shipped', To_Date('11.10.2062', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '-'] = Count(DISTINCT ORDER_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1), ANY] || '/' || Count(DISTINCT LINE_ITEM_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1), ANY] || '/' || Nvl(Sum(SHIPPED_QTY)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1), ANY], 0),
                      TWO_DAYS_AGO['Orders/Lines/Units Shipped', To_Date('11.10.2062', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '-'] = Count(DISTINCT ORDER_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 2), ANY] || '/' || Count(DISTINCT LINE_ITEM_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 2), ANY] || '/' || Nvl(Sum(SHIPPED_QTY)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 2), ANY], 0),
                      THREE_DAYS_AGO['Orders/Lines/Units Shipped', To_Date('11.10.2062', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '-'] = Count(DISTINCT ORDER_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 3), ANY] || '/' || Count(DISTINCT LINE_ITEM_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 3), ANY] || '/' || Nvl(Sum(SHIPPED_QTY)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 3), ANY], 0),
                      FOUR_DAYS_AGO['Orders/Lines/Units Shipped', To_Date('11.10.2062', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '-'] = Count(DISTINCT ORDER_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 4), ANY] || '/' || Count(DISTINCT LINE_ITEM_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 4), ANY] || '/' || Nvl(Sum(SHIPPED_QTY)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 4), ANY], 0),
                      FIVE_DAYS_AGO['Orders/Lines/Units Shipped', To_Date('11.10.2062', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '-'] = Count(DISTINCT ORDER_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 5), ANY] || '/' || Count(DISTINCT LINE_ITEM_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 5), ANY] || '/' || Nvl(Sum(SHIPPED_QTY)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 5), ANY], 0),
                      SIX_DAYS_AGO['Orders/Lines/Units Shipped', To_Date('11.10.2062', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '-'] = Count(DISTINCT ORDER_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 6), ANY] || '/' || Count(DISTINCT LINE_ITEM_ID)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 6), ANY] || '/' || Nvl(Sum(SHIPPED_QTY)['xxx', TRUNC(SYSDATE - 6), ANY], 0)
                  )
)
WHERE       FACILITY_ACTIVITY != 'xxx'
ORDER BY    WHSE

--  R e s u l t :
WHSE FACILITY_ACTIVITY                TODAY                            YESTERDAY                        TWO_DAYS_AGO                     THREE_DAYS_AGO                   FOUR_DAYS_AGO                    FIVE_DAYS_AGO                    SIX_DAYS_AGO                   
---- -------------------------------- -------------------------------- -------------------------------- -------------------------------- -------------------------------- -------------------------------- -------------------------------- --------------------------------
DCV  Orders/Lines/Units Shipped       1/1/20                           0/0/0                            0/0/0                            2/1/20                           2/2/65                           1/1/25                           1/1/20                           
DCV  Lines/Units Picked               1/30                             0/0                              0/0                              1/20                             2/70                             1/50                             1/30                             
DXX  Orders/Lines/Units Shipped       1/1/40                           0/0/0                            0/0/0                            2/2/75                           1/1/40                           1/1/70                           1/1/70                           
DXX  Lines/Units Picked               1/50                             0/0                              0/0                              2/90                             1/40                             1/90                             1/80
```

The groupings (Partition By and Dimension By) could be (should be) adjusted to your needs as well as anything else. The main advantage is that you can have control of practicaly every "cell" with values. More about the MODEL clause [here](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm)